# Unexpected behaviour after calling sub-route

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a wrapper route (WrapperRoute) which can call different sub-routes.
My problem is, that depending on the exception handling in the sub-route the wrapper route proceeds differently after calling.

When the sub-route has no error (NoErrorRoute), no exception handling (ErrorRouteUnhandled) or handles the exception in a try-catch block (ErrorRouteTryCatch) the WrapperRoute works correctly. That means that the WrapperRoute works until end and writes the last log.

When the sub-route has an onException-definition (ErrorRouteHandled), only the finally-block from the WrapperRoute will be executed. The last log from the route will not be shown.

Why stops the WrapperRoute after the try-catch block?

This is my complete code for testing this behavior. In each test case I wrote the logs.

**In the test case handledTest is the last log missing from the WrapperRoute.**

```
package test;

import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.junit.Test;

import at.mic.edis.test.TemplateCamelTest;

public class ExcepionHandlingTest extends TemplateCamelTest{

    @Test
    public void noErrorTest() throws Exception {
        template.sendBodyAndHeader("direct:WRAPPER", "BODY", "SUBROUTE", "direct:NO-ERROR");
//      2014-11-20 10:35:23,335 [main] INFO  route1 - WRAPPER-Start
//      2014-11-20 10:35:23,350 [main] INFO  route2 - NO-ERROR-ROUTE: run without exception
//      2014-11-20 10:35:23,353 [main] INFO  route1 - WRAPPER: Finally
//      2014-11-20 10:35:23,353 [main] INFO  route1 - WRAPPER: End of wrapper route
    }

    @Test
    public void unhandledTest() throws Exception {
        template.sendBodyAndHeader("direct:WRAPPER", "BODY", "SUBROUTE", "direct:UNHANDLED");
//      2014-11-20 10:36:34,932 [main] INFO  route1 - WRAPPER-Start
//      2014-11-20 10:36:34,948 [main] INFO  route3 - UNHANDLED: throw exception
//      2014-11-20 10:36:34,952 [main] INFO  route1 - WRAPPER: Catch exception
//      2014-11-20 10:36:34,953 [main] INFO  route1 - WRAPPER: Finally
//      2014-11-20 10:36:34,953 [main] INFO  route1 - WRAPPER: End of wrapper route
    }

    @Test
    public void handledTest() throws Exception {
        template.sendBodyAndHeader("direct:WRAPPER", "BODY", "SUBROUTE", "direct:HANDLED");
//      2014-11-20 10:37:47,898 [main] INFO  route1 - WRAPPER-Start
//      2014-11-20 10:37:47,913 [main] INFO  route4 - HANDLED: throw exception
//      2014-11-20 10:37:47,916 [main] INFO  route4 - HANDLED: Exception handled
//      2014-11-20 10:37:47,919 [main] INFO  route1 - WRAPPER: Finally
    }

    @Test
    public void tryCatchTest() throws Exception {
        template.sendBodyAndHeader("direct:WRAPPER", "BODY", "SUBROUTE", "direct:TRY-CATCH");
//      2014-11-20 10:38:55,871 [main] INFO  route1 - WRAPPER-Start
//      2014-11-20 10:38:55,887 [main] INFO  route5 - TRY-CATCH: throw exception
//      2014-11-20 10:38:55,889 [main] INFO  route5 - TRY-CATCH: exception caught
//      2014-11-20 10:38:55,890 [main] INFO  route5 - TRY-CATCH: finish
//      2014-11-20 10:38:55,891 [main] INFO  route1 - WRAPPER: Finally
//      2014-11-20 10:38:55,892 [main] INFO  route1 - WRAPPER: End of wrapper route
    }

    @Override
    public RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                WrapperRoute wrapper = new WrapperRoute();
                NoErrorRoute noError = new NoErrorRoute();
                ErrorRouteUnhandled unhandled = new ErrorRouteUnhandled();
                ErrorRouteHandled handled = new ErrorRouteHandled();
                ErrorRouteTryCatch tryCatch = new ErrorRouteTryCatch();

                CamelContext context = getContext();
                context.addRoutes(wrapper);
                context.addRoutes(noError);
                context.addRoutes(unhandled);
                context.addRoutes(handled);
                context.addRoutes(tryCatch);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

WrapperRoute:

```
package test;

import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;

import at.mic.edis.all.scheduler.processor.WrappedRoutingSlipBean;

public class WrapperRoute extends RouteBuilder{

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        onException(Exception.class)
            .handled(true)
            .log("WRAPPER: exception handler");

        from("direct:WRAPPER")
            .log("WRAPPER-Start")
            .doTry()
                .recipientList().method(WrappedEndpoint.class.getName())                
                .end()
            .doCatch(Exception.class)
                .log("WRAPPER: Catch exception")
            .doFinally()
                .log("WRAPPER: Finally")
            .end()
            .log("WRAPPER: End of wrapper route");
    }
}
```

WrapperEndpoint:

```
package test;

import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Handler;

public class WrappedEndpoint {

    @Handler
    public Object process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        //Reads the direct endpoint for the subroute from the header
        String endpoint = (String) exchange.getIn().getHeader("SUBROUTE");
        return endpoint;
    }
}
```

NoErrorRoute:

```
package test;

import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;

public class NoErrorRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("direct:NO-ERROR")
            .log("NO-ERROR-ROUTE: run without exception");
    }
}
```

ErrorRouteUnhandled:

```
package test;

import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;

public class ErrorRouteUnhandled extends RouteBuilder{

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("direct:UNHANDLED")
            .log("UNHANDLED: throw exception")
            .throwException(new Exception("Exception"));
    }
}
```

ErrorRouteHandled:

```
package test;

import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;

public class ErrorRouteHandled extends RouteBuilder{

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        onException(Exception.class)
            .handled(true)
            .log("HANDLED: Exception handled");

        from("direct:HANDLED")
            .log("HANDLED: throw exception")
            .throwException(new Exception("Exception"));
    }
}
```

ErrorRouteTryCatch:

```
package test;

import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;

public class ErrorRouteTryCatch extends RouteBuilder{

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("direct:TRY-CATCH")
            .log("TRY-CATCH: throw exception")
            .doTry()
                .throwException(new Exception("Exception"))
            .doCatch(Exception.class)
                .log("TRY-CATCH: exception caught")
            .end()
            .log("TRY-CATCH: finish");
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

It is possible to set the property *Exchange.ERRORHANDLER_HANDLED* (=*CamelErrorHandlerHandled*) to false. This is the same way how the properties look when no error handling is defined or when *.handled(false)* is set in the onException-block.

I modified the doFinally()-block from the WrapperRoute and now all works:

```
...
.doFinally()
    .process(new Processor() {
        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            // Print all properties
            for (Entry<String, Object>  entry: exchange.getProperties().entrySet()){
                System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " | " + entry.getValue());
            }
            if (exchange.getProperty(Exchange.ERRORHANDLER_HANDLED)!=null){
                System.out.println("Set error handler property to false");
                exchange.setProperty(Exchange.ERRORHANDLER_HANDLED, false);
            }
        }
    })
    .log("WRAPPER: Finally")
.end()
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `handled` set from `true` (= no failure returned to client) to `false` in `ErrorRouteHandled`, the last log entry is shown again:

```
onException(Exception.class)
    .handled(false) // changed from true to false
    .log("HANDLED: Exception handled");
```

If set to `true` only one step in the `doFinally()` part is processed.

Actually, I don't know, if this is a bug or if it works as designed.

Comment: Thank you for the hint but it is not opinion for me to change all onException-blocks from all my routes because they are more than 200.
It ist possible to set the property in the doFinally-Block from the WrapperRoute (see my EDIT). This leads also to the behavior that more than one step can be processed.

Comment: @lahu89 You should not set `handled` to true if it is not used that way. Setting `Exchange.ERRORHANDLER_HANDLED` may be a solution. But this looks like magic and should be avoided.

Comment: `handled(true)` is correct for all my other routes. The WrapperRoute is only a new feature in my programm to call dynamically other routes from outside and to monitore the result. I know it looks like magic and should be avoided but I see currently no other opinion and it was the first solution I found.